# Icons on menus have disappeared

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons

When i right click to bring up a menu, for example on the desktop, i have 'open terminal here' which i know should have a terminal icon next to this however it doesn't. Any ideas? I had a poke around in gconf-editor but didn't have much luck (though i didn't try very hard ;)

Thanks

Comment: What flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In gconf-editor go to desktop -> gnome -> interface and check the checkbox for menus_have_icons. There's also a buttons_have_icons which you may want to enable.

This was a delibrate 'feature' in Gnome 2.28, from which Ubuntu 10.04 for built.

These two options can also be changed through the "Gnome settings" panel of [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), see screenshot below. (Ubuntu Tweak can be installed through a PPA)
[image: Ubuntu Tweak - Gnome Settings Panel]

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, the gconf settings worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

fluteflute's answer is excellent, but in case anyone wanted to change this setting without using Ubuntu Tweak, you can do this by changing the following two gconf settings to true using gconf-editor (a GUI program) or gconftool (a command line program):

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_has_icons --type bool true
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons --type bool true
```