# Missing icons in dropdown menus in Eclipse

Tags: 11.10, unity, icons, menu, eclipse

Icons don't appear in dropdown menus in Eclipse. I know that in Gnome this bug can be cured by this way: [Icons on menus have disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2236/icons-on-menus-have-disappeared) but it doesn't work in Unity. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same issue in Eclipse Indigo in Ubuntu 11.10. Ubuntu Tweak did the trick for me.

Just go to **Tweaks** > **Miscellaneous** > **Menus have icons**

[image]

I also enabled **Buttons have icons** for good measure.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Hooray. That's been bothering me for a while ! As an aside, I am running 14.04 with Cinnamon. Fix was Preferences | Themes | Other Settings and then 'Show icons in menus'  (and the related 'Show icons on buttons). Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 12.10, install **[Gnome Tweak Tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool)** and enable icons in **Theme**

Answer (score 5):

For **Ubuntu 14.04** I couldn't find that setting in either `unity-tweak-tool` or `gnome-tweak-tool`. While you can use gconf-editor, it has no effect in eclipse. Instead the following worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
```

Comment: Ok well thatth might be where the setting is, but it has no effect

Comment: On Kubuntu, there is the possibility to configure the icons for buttons directly in the system settings (-> Style -> GTK). That fixed the issue for me without installing any additional tools.

Comment: Have changed the answer from gconf-editor to gsettings which does work

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, use:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/menus-have-icons true
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/buttons-have-icons true
```

Comment: If that works, then using `gsettings` should work fine too: http://askubuntu.com/a/553394/158442

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 20.04 running GNOME Shell 3.36.7.